# C# null 許容参照型を教えて！

Tags: c#, wpf

教えてください。
画像の赤枠部分はnull許容型じゃないのにnullが来るかも？というワーニングらしいです。
このワーニングが表示されないように正しくコーディングする方法を教えてください。

[image: null許容型のエラー]

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: どういうメッセージが出てるのか書きましょう。

Comment: 他人のコードのコピーのようですが、であれば出展も書きましょう。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### `Value.ToString`

`Value.ToString()`は`object.ToString()`のオーバーライドとみなされると思います。
`object.ToString()`は戻り値が`string?`と`null`許容参照型になっていますが、`Type.GetField`は`null`を許容しないので警告となります。
https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=net-7.0

この場合、`null`チェックや`string.InNullOrEmpty`によるチェックを入れる必要があるでしょう。

```
var toString = Value.ToStrin();
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(toString)) return null;
var fieldInfo = Value.GetType().GetField(toString);
```

### `GetCustomAttribute`

次に、`GetCustomAttribute`メソッドも戻り値が`Attribute?`と`null`許容参照型になっています。
https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.reflection.customattributeextensions.getcustomattribute?view=net-7.0#system-reflection-customattributeextensions-getcustomattribute(system-reflection-memberinfo-system-type)

キャストにおいて`DescriptionAttribute?`あたりにしておくところでしょうか？

```
var attr = (DescriptionAttribute?)
    fieldInfo.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DescriptionAttribute));
```

### 戻り値

このメソッドは`string`型、つまり`null`を許容していません。
`null`を返したいなら、メソッド自体の戻り値も`string?`とする必要があります。

または、`return null;`をやめて、`return string.Empty;`などと空の文字列を返すこともありでしょう。